# Rails: Cycle Producing Same Result Every Time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cycle

I'm trying to create a zebra-striped series of divs with the following code:

```
= content_tag_for(:div, conversation.receipts_for(current_user), :class => cycle("odd", "even")) do |receipt|
  %p=receipt.content
```

In theory, the class names should cycle between "receipt odd" and "receipt even" for each row. Instead, I get "receipt odd" every single time. I've tried using unordered lists and tables as well, but they don't work properly either. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't work, the way you've written it. `cycle` is called *once* at the time you call `content_tag_for`, and it returns `"odd"`. It is *that value*, `"odd"`, that is passed into `content_tag_for`, *not* the function `cycle`. Unless `content_tag_for` accepts a block/lambda for its `style` argument, you cannot do what you are trying to do.

In essence, you're calling a function and passing in the *return value* of a second function:

```
func1( func2() )
```

---

The best way to handle this is via collection rendering.

In your view:

```
= render conversation.receipts_for(current_user)
```

In a separate partial, probably `app/views/receipts/_receipt.html.haml`:

```
= div_for receipt, :class => cycle('odd', 'even')
  %p=receipt.content
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I haven't read into lambdas before, but the func1( func2()) analogy makes a lot of sense. For the time being though, I'm going to keep my solution, as it's a bit more readable than rendering a partial.

Comment: You should really, really get used to partials. Rendering a collection with a partial is the **Rails Way**, and if you find it unreadable you're not doing it often enough. You should almost never have to resort to the kind of loop you're using in your answer.

Comment: Well, if it's the convention, then I'm cool with this solution. Still, I was under the impression that partials were primarily used to refactor code that appears in multiple places. In this scenario, it only seems to clutter the file structure. What's the advantage of using a partial over code that can be contained in a single file?

Comment: Readability, maintainability and especially performance. It wins across the board and is considered a [best practice](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/38-use-render-collection-rails-3-when-possible).

Comment: 3 times faster benchmarking? I'm sold. Thanks for the thorough reply!

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to get this working with the somewhat uglier:

```
-conversation.receipts_for(current_user).each do |receipt|
  %div{:class => cycle("receipt odd", "receipt even")}
    %p=receipt.content
```

If anyone kind find a more elegant solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This is in slim, not haml, syntax aside, the concept is there:

```
= div_for(conversation.receipts_for(current_user)) do |receipt|
  p class=cycle("odd", "even")
    = receipt.content.try(:html_safe)
```

I agree that getting used to partials is a must if you are doing Rails development, but I like to avoid calling partials in loops (for collections) - mostly so it doesn't add noise to the development log, not sure about the performance implications of one approach vs the other (some discussion [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/157108/rails-does-using-partials-slow-views-rendering))

Answer (score 0):

You should add a name for your cycle. If you have two cycles in the same block without names, they will cycle each other out and will produce the same result.

```
cycle("odd", "even", name: "cycle_name")
```

For your case, I would do

```
-conversation.receipts_for(current_user).each do |receipt|
  = content_tag_for(:div, receipt, :class => cycle("odd", "even", name: "receipt")) 
    %p=receipt.content
```

[Cycle Reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-cycle)